# Maven: compilation module fails

Tags: maven

I've these modules into my `pom.xml`:

```
<modules>
    <module>rep-digital-common</module>
    <module>rep-digital-api</module>
</modules>
```

So, `rep-digital-common` contains common classes `rep-digital-api` module needs.

When I compile them using

```
$ mvn clean compile
...
[INFO] rep-digital-common ................................. SUCCESS [  7.571 s]
[INFO] rep-digital-api .................................... SUCCESS [ 17.988 s]
```

However, when I perform:

```
$ mvn -pl rep-digital-api clean package
```

it fails:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.345 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-28T12:29:19+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 58M/140M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project rep-digital-api: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /home/jcabre/projectes/repo-digital/rep-digital-api/src/main/java/net/gencat/transversal/repositori/digital/document/service/DocumentService.java:[29,65] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class ContentStatus
```

`ContentStatus` symbol is located on `rep-digital-common`. I don't quite figure out what's going wrong.

Obviously, `rep-digital-common` is added as a `rep-digital-api` dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.gencat.transversal.repositori.digital</groupId>
    <artifactId>rep-digital-common</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It was already been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing `mvn clean compile`  or `mvn clean package` don't add the built artifacts in the local repository.
To add built artifacts in the local repository you have to use `mvn clean install`.

Note that as actually you build a reactor project, it works because the reactor provides dependencies needed to each current module to build.

On the other hand, as you compile `rep-digital-api` alone, the reactor will not help you :

```
 mvn -pl rep-digital-api clean package
```

and so the compilation can only fail as `rep-digital-common` classes are not resolvable.